# How to get HTML select , dropdown for two select element?

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have problem with HTML `select` element. I want to show a dropdown select and when I change location, this will show me two different prices.

In my example, when I change the country (Australia) and city (Canberra or Sydney), I want a price for 30 days and 90 days.

[image: Screenshot : <code>http://s14.postimg.org/4qajfiu5d/pricing.png</code>]

Here's the [JSFiddle for my code](http://jsfiddle.net/hassanfiddle2015d/4uzng0ay/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$city = $("#city").val()
if($city=="Sydney"){
   $(htmlElement).html("Price you want to display")    
}
```

This is one way of doing what you are looking for

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your suggestion.  Did you check my code in js fiddle. i tried lot. I hope a better sugession .

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, missed that entirely, it seems like you already have the mechanism in place to get the value of the selected options, why not just use logic to determine what you want to display? I edited my answer to be more in line with what you're looking for.

Comment: i get the value for Sydney only for one side ( 30 days ) but need for both like 30 days and 90 days. 
and now i have another problem, when i change Sydney to Canberra , need to remove Sydney price and replace Canberra price. hope his make clear.

Comment: That's where the .html function comes in, it replaces all html within that element with whatever you put as it's parameters. Check this out for more information on how to use it http://api.jquery.com/html/